# Strange "local" folder inside virtualenv folder

Tags: python, virtualenv

After I create my virtualenv environment (VE), inside it there is a symbolic link named "local". It points to the VE folder, which means that if you open it you end up in the same folder that you started in.

I wouldn't care about that, but it makes some autocompletion "wizards" in PyCharm unusable (they show the same item over and over again, each time with a deeper nesting level).

Somehow I cannot find any hint about this problem (I'm using virtualenv 1.6.4).

The question is: what's that "local" symlink used for ?

Comment: Still a problem but PyCharm today just duplicates symbols. Report and workaround: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32209.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [the source](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/112b6a22452b3ed813943f092f48031d3477d081/virtualenv.py#L1294) the `local` symlink was put in place as a fix for [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/839588)
that affected platforms using the ["posix_local" install scheme](http://distribute.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.6.15-1ubuntu1/classsetuptools_1_1command_1_1easy__install_1_1easy__install_a6b9fdcfbd834e17bcae79da5584e3c97.html). This change was introduced in [version 1.6.3](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/changes/#id52).

The problem you described has been addressed by this [pull request](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/pull/166) on github. This proposed patch changes the symlinks to point to an actual `local` directory rather than the parent directory. <strike>It is yet to be merged.</strike> This patch has since been [applied](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/commit/5cb7cd652953441a6696c15bdac3c4f9746dfaa1) so the problem should be fixed in the next release (1.7.1 perhaps?).

Comment: This is one of the best (most thorough) answers I have received on StackOverflow up to date. Thank you!

Comment: The pull request is now closed so the problem should disappear soon.

Comment: @ShawnChin what is "posix_local" install scheme in this context? Do you mean /usr/local/?

Comment: @guettli See the linked page. It's essentially `$base/local/*` which would indeed default to `/usr/local` if a prefix is not defined.