# virtualenv on Ubuntu symlink local/lib -> ../lib?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualenv

If I create a virtualenv on Ubuntu 16.04 (Python2), then a directory `local` gets created which contains symlinks:

```
===> virtualenv symlinktest
New python executable in /home/tguettler/tmp/symlinktest/bin/python
Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /home/tguettler/.pydistutils.cfg file.
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.



===> ls -l symlinktest/local/



===> ls -l symlinktest/local/*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tguettler tguettler 35 Mär  7 14:21 symlinktest/local/bin -> /home/tguettler/tmp/symlinktest/bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tguettler tguettler 39 Mär  7 14:21 symlinktest/local/include -> /home/tguettler/tmp/symlinktest/include
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tguettler tguettler 35 Mär  7 14:21 symlinktest/local/lib -> /home/tguettler/tmp/symlinktest/lib


===> virtualenv --version
15.0.3
```

This does not happen on other linux distributions.

Why and where does this symlink get created?

## Update

On this plattform `openSUSE 42.1 (x86_64)` a symlink from lib64 to lib gets created ...

I don't understand the need for this symlink.

Comment: Wondering if we can somehow deduce that from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227120/strange-local-folder-inside-virtualenv-folder

Comment: @nir0s I don't run a five year old virtualenv :-) I use version 15.0.3. I use the same virtualenv version on SuSE linux and there the symlink does not get created. Nevertheless thank you for looking at my issue.

Answer (score 1):

So, after prying into the virtualenv code just a tad, it seems that the following happens:

`create_environment` calls `install_python` which calls `fix_local_scheme` (https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/master/virtualenv.py#L1492).
Note how in the docstring they state that this is needed for posix systems like Ubuntu with Python 2.7 (which you're running)

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.linux_distribution()
('Ubuntu', '16.04', 'xenial')

$ python2.7
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig._get_default_scheme()
'posix_local'


$ cat /usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py
def _get_default_scheme():
    if os.name == 'posix':
        # the default scheme for posix on Debian/Ubuntu is posix_local
        # FIXME: return dist-packages/posix_prefix only for
        #   is_default_prefix and 'PYTHONUSERBASE' not in os.environ and 'real_prefix' not in sys.__dict__
        # is_default_prefix = not prefix or os.path.normpath(prefix) in ('/usr', '/usr/local')
        return 'posix_local'
    return os.name
```

You can also read the explanation on the different prefixes: https://pymotw.com/2/sysconfig/#installation-paths, for more information.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Now I see where the symlink gets created.... Leaving only one question left: Why is this needed?