# virtualenv creates directory called 'local' on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04

If I create a virtualenv with Ubuntu 18.04, then a directory called `local` gets created.

```
virtualenv test-env
cd test-env
ls -l local/
```

Output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 foo foo 30 Jan 30 10:47 bin -> /home/foo/tmp/test-env/bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 foo foo 34 Jan 30 10:47 include -> /home/foo/tmp/test-env/include
lrwxrwxrwx 1 foo foo 30 Jan 30 10:47 lib -> /home/foo/tmp/test-env/lib
```

Version:

```
virtualenv --version
15.0.3
```

This does not happen on other machines (for example enterprise SuSE Linux)

AFAIK this directory is not needed.

Is there a way to avoid this directory called `local` which is not needed?

(This is about Python 2.7)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Digging through the docs, and some older SO posts, I stumbled on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227120/strange-local-folder-inside-virtualenv-folder) answer, and the official [Release Notes](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/changes/?highlight=local).

On my `Ubuntu 16.04` and `virtualenv 15.0.1` combo, the `~/.local` folder holds all Python-related libraries, documentation, and binaries.

I suspect that virtualenv is trying to "match" this approach, in order to retain compatibility with scripts run on the bare system, as the Python `$PATH` looks there for Python-related modules, packages, etc.

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)

/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
...
/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
...
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

If I run the same command inside my virtualenv, I get both directories in my Python path.

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)

/home/<username>/python-venv-tests/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7
...
/home/<username>/python-venv-tests/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/home/<username>/python-venv-tests/lib/python2.7/site-packages
...
```

So, to answer your question

- This `.local` directory contains only symlinks to the 'proper' `/bin, /include, /lib` of your virtual environment, so there's no danger of duplicate libraries
- This is most possibly done as a compatibility measure to Ubuntu using `~/.local` for Python packages
- This means you're free to delete this and/or change your Python `$PATH` if you really need to, but it will not have any impact on your workflow (or if you plan to migrate the virtual env to a different host).
- Generally speaking, I'd suggest keeping it as-is, so that the virtual environment matches the system structure as much as possible, and that other scripts/users that may have hard-coded values depending on it avoid errors.

Comment: Good find! @Shafikur Rahman can you verify that the folder is a symlink by `ls -la` within the folder that contains the `local` directory?

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu virtualenv imitates the machine's installation, and local is part of that.
If you want to ignore this in your project, you can add it to `.gitignore`

Comment: Could you please explain why "local" is part of ubuntu? This does not exist: /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: Not sure about that. Most probably it relates to python installation.